# Rolling mean with irregular boundaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy, moving-average

I am using rolling mean on my data to smoothen it. My `data` can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvOwxMj91-ZmgYkxDwJiNuOzovgasQ).

An illustration of my original data is;
[image: Original Data]

Currently, I am using

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
window_length = 9
res = pd.rolling_mean(np.array(data[:, 2]), window_length, min_periods=1, center=True)
```

This is what I get after applying rolling mean with a window_length of 9;

[image: Rolling Mean]

And when i increase the window_length to 20, I get a smoother image but at boundaries, the data seems to be erroneous.

[image]

The problem is, as seen in the figures above, the rolling mean introduces some sort of errors at the boundaries of my data which do not exist in the original data.

Is there any way to correct this?

My guess is, at the boundary, since part of the `window_length` is found outside my data, it exaggerates the mean.

Is there a way to correct this error using pandas rolling mean or is there a better pythonic way in doing this? Thanks.

Ps. I am aware the panda function of rolling mean i am using is deprecated in the new versión.

Comment: Glancing at your data and graph, it seems like you are trying to apply a 1-dimensional solution to a 2-dimensional problem.  It wouldn't be too hard (conceptually) to make this more of a 2-d style smoother, but it'd be slow (both to code and run) and I'm sure there are some mapping-type libraries to do what you want (though I don't know offhand what they are)

Comment: @JohnE, but aside the boudaries which are presenting errors, the function Works fine.

Comment: Are you sure it's working?  I mean, maybe it is but I can't tell by looking and it just doesn't make sense to me based on the 1d/2d issue I already mentioned.  This is really a lot more data than is ideal for an SO question.  Honestly I'd suggest deleting this question and reposting with a much smaller sample version of the data.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  emphasis on the "minimal" part ;-)

Comment: @JohnE, yeah it is working. All I want to do is to smoothen only datas found within my figure. That is, I do not want to apply the rolling function to boundary data. In that way, i do not get artefacts like i am getting in the boundaries of figure 2

Answer (score 0):

You can try a native 2D convolution method such as [`scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html) with weights so just make the kernel an average (mean) function.

The weights would be:

```
n = 3. # size of kernel over which to calculate mean
weights = np.ones(n,n)/n**2
```

If the white area of your data are represented by nans, this would reduce the footprint of the result by `n` since any kernel stamp with a nan included will return a nan. If this is really an issue try look at [astropy.convolution](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/convolution/), which has better nan handling.